# Redirect posts to post editor page based on query string

Tags: php, plugin-development, wp-redirect

I want the posts that has the param `edit` to open the respective post editor page.

This is because the admin bar is disabled on my site. So I need to make things easier to edit on my sites.

I made the following code and inserted it in my plugin, but it's not working. I tried `header("Location: ")` instead of `wp_safe_redirect`, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

```php
function myfunction() {
    if( isset( $_GET['edit'] ) && empty( $_GET['edit'] ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( admin_url( '/post.php?action=edit&post=' . get_the_ID() ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Implementation notes:

1. You need to use that function with an appropriate action hook. For example, `template_redirect` hook can be used here.
2. If you want URL to have `?edit`, then `empty` check is not necessary, if you want URL to have something like `?edit=1`, then use `! empty` check.
3. Check and ignore if we are already on the `admin` pages.
4. Check and proceed if we are on a single `post` page.

### CODE:

Following is an example code that'll work:

```php
function fyz_edit_redirect() {
    if( ! is_admin() // skip if we are on admin pages already
            && is_single() // apply only if it's a single post
            && isset( $_GET['edit'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['edit'] ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( admin_url( '/post.php?action=edit&post=' . get_the_ID() ) );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fyz_edit_redirect' );
```

Comment: Thank you bro, I was using the wrong hook. Cheers!